# Hair is rendering distorted

Tags: rendering, particles, hair

I'm rendering a paintbrush, and the hair look as expected in preview, but render wavy and distorted. Problem occurs in eevee as well as cycles. Brush tip particles were shaped by scaling points along the strands. Problem does not occur when hair is not edited
[image: Viewport render]

[image: render]

UPDATE: found that subdivision surface was disabled in render, and that helped things along, but I'm still having weird issues with editing.
[image: the new result]

[image]

The particle edit picture is the 4th brush. others are similarly edited

Comment: There are a few settings in Blender which can be different in viewport and render for example Subdivision Surface modifier. Those can cause similar artifacts.

Comment: Subsurf was the problem! thank you!

Comment: I spoke too soon. Subsurf was only part of the problem..